# Can "FLEX JS" be used like a js plugin

Tags: javascript, flash, adobe, flexjs

recently i visited [APACHE FLEXJS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexJS) and it says `flexjs` can work without `flash/air`.Now i face the situation to work with flash but flash not supported in ios.So can i choose `flexjs` for this?or When i go to `flexjs'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FlexJS with PhoneGap. Or you can run FlexJS apps directly in Safari on IOS devices.

This link should be able to give you an idea in detail when to use FlexJS: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexJS